# How to make hierarchical/zoomable ticks in D3?

Tags: d3.js, hierarchical

I am working with mathematics book data, but my question applies to general hierarchical formats. The book is structured with chapters, sections, objectives, and exercises. A chapter has a variable number of sections. Each section has a variable number of objectives. And each objective has a variable number of exercises. I am wanting to make zoomable visualizations such that when all the way zoomed out, ticks demarcate chapters. When zooming in, however, I want the ticks to demarcate sections when appropriate and then when zooming in even more, I want to show objectives and then exercises. What is the best way of approaching this? I have even wondered about using a [partition layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Partition-Layout) and translating the x and dx values, but this doesn't really help me for the transition from one level in the hierarchy to another.

Comment: It sounds like you would need to, depending on the zoom level, choose the data set (i.e. ticks) to display and then display them. No need for layouts or anything fancy like that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Lars. I ended up using layouts. My results are at http://bl.ocks.org/tommct/8191276. I'd be curious to hear if you think there's a better approach.

Comment: I'm sure that things could be simplified a bit, but apart from that it looks good to me. If that solved your problem, would you mind posting it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using layouts and chose to direct the ticks to different ordinal scales. My results are at bl.ocks.org/tommct/8191276.